# Software with a universal printing driver

Tags: printing, device-driver

I work for a private company in Italy, and I have a big issue with printers in my office. We have more than 30, located on two different floors, and are different models/manufacturers.

Does anybody know of the existence of a software that can let me print with a universal driver?

Comment: I don't think that will be possible since the printer manufacturers provide the drivers for their particular printers.

Comment: That is a very complicated driver but it is remotely possible. However at minimum we'll need to know what OS(es) you want that for as well as what kind of cost range.

Answer (score 1):

1. There is an HP universal and a Xerox global driver.  Otherwise you will have to have a file share on the network to hold the individual drivers.
2. Another solution involves setting up print queues for each printer.  If you had a windows server, you could setup 30 print queues.  The server would hold all 30 drivers, and each client could automatically download the drivers from the server.  You would have to have a computer with enough memory,processor, and etc to handle the printing work load.
3. Windows includes scripts:

   C:\Windows\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US

   prndrvr.vbs

   and more
   Which allow you to install drivers remotely over the network.  You will need a printer driver repository, visible to all PC, to host the drivers.